# Rails logger level changes to ERROR abruptly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, thread-safety

I am experiencing very strange behavior with my Rails logs. Wherein the logger level automatically/abruptly changes to ERROR(:error. logger level code 3) instead of whatever it was supposed to be (:debug or :info).

*Here in this image the log level is as expected. **Debug or level 0***

[image: good logs showing all info. level 0 means debug]

*But within few minutes(at most 2 minutes) the logger level changes to 3(**3 stands for ERROR**)*

[image]

I came across a [github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20490) which explains Rails logger is not thread safe, I am using passenger in ***thread*** mode as opposed to *process* which it was previously. Could this be a reason for such behavior ?

What could be other possibilities, that changes the logger level from 0 to 3 ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with thread safeness. There is only one answer to your question: Your application or a gem your app depends on changes the log level.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22425
active_record session-store does a log silencing everytime it get's, set's or destroy's a session.

Due to passenger thread mode, there's a race condition in LoggerSilence

--

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb#L48

Now if two or more threads enter that method in parallel, there's a chance that only the first call sees the real log level and a second call sees the temporary_level, because the real log level was overriden by the first call but not reset yet. Now when this call ends the log level is not properly reset (it's reset to the wrong temporary value) and thus logging stays disabled.

--

I haven't been able to fix the issue yet, but will be soon.